# Meaning of "not without parts"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-meaning

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XIX, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_19)

Passage 298

> Such was our first interview, the first of many; and in all he showed the same attractive qualities and defects. His taste for literature was native and unaffected; his sentimentality, although extreme and a thought ridiculous, was plainly genuine. I wondered at my own innocent wonder. I knew that Homer nodded, that Cæsar had compiled a jest-book, that Turner lived by preference the life of Puggy Booth, that Shelley made paper boats, and Wordsworth wore green spectacles! and with all this mass of evidence before me, I had expected Bellairs to be entirely of one piece, subdued to what he worked in, a spy all through. As I abominated the man's trade, so I had expected to detest the man himself; and behold, I liked him. Poor devil! he was essentially a man on wires, all sensibility and tremor, brimful of a cheap poetry, **not without parts**, quite without courage. His boldness was despair; the gulf behind him thrust him on; he was one of those who might commit a murder rather than confess the theft of a postage-stamp.

I suppose *parts* means something like *faculties* there. If so, is this usage common nowadays or is it obsolete? Is there a synonym?

**Editing:**

I looked *parts* up once again and found

(Collins English Dictionary):
Definition of *'of many parts'*

**of many parts**

in British English

**having many different abilities**

> *He really is a man of many parts, is there no end to his talent?
> Times, Sunday Times (2008)*
>
> *He was a man of many parts: he divided his time and considerable energies between politics, the law and journalism, with equal distinction.
> Times, Sunday Times (2007)*

[of many parts](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-many-parts)

So, *of many parts* seems to be an idiom and *parts* in *not without parts* means the same as in *of many parts*.

Comment: [part 8](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/part) "a constituent of character or capacity : TALENT. *a man of many parts*"

Comment: Not a current idiom.